# WordPress Yoast SEO Plugin and opengraph tags

Tags: wordpress, facebook-opengraph

I have a wordpress page that is dynamic. WordPress SEO By Yoast adds opengraph tags to all pages which isn't a problem except on this one page.

Is there a way to overwrite the meta tags with more dynamic content?

Answer (score 8):

Looking through the code of Yoast SEO, I found many "undocumented" filters you can use. Here is a list extracted from it:

> `wpseo_opengraph_author_facebook` - Allow developers to filter the
>   Yoast SEO post authors facebook profile URL
>   `wpseo_opengraph_admin` - Allow developer to filter the fb:admins
>   string put out by Yoast SEO `wpseo_opengraph_title` - Allow changing
>   the title specifically for OpenGraph
>  `wpseo_opengraph_url` - Allow
>   changing the OpenGraph URL `wpseo_opengraph_type` - Allow changing the
>   OpenGraph type of the page
>  `wpseo_opengraph_desc` - Allow changing
>   the OpenGraph description
>  `wpseo_opengraph_site_name` - Allow
>   changing the OpenGraph site name `wpseo_opengraph_show_publish_date` -
>   Allow showing publication date for other post types
>   `wpseo_opengraph_image_size` - Allow changing the image size used for
>   OpenGraph sharing `wpseo_opengraph_image` - Allow changing the
>   OpenGraph image.
>  `wpseo_twitter_card_type` - Allow changing the
>   Twitter Card type as output in the Twitter card by Yoast SEO
>   `wpseo_twitter_metatag_key` - Make the Twitter metatag key
>   filterable
>  `wpseo_twitter_description` - Allow changing the
>   Twitter description as output in the Twitter card by Yoast SEO
>   `wpseo_twitter_title` - Allow changing the Twitter title as output in
>   the Twitter card by Yoast SEO `wpseo_twitter_site` - Allow changing
>   the Twitter site account as output in the Twitter card by Yoast
>   SEO
>  `wpseo_twitter_image` - Allow changing the Twitter Card
>   image
>  `wpseo_twitter_image_size` - Allow changing the Twitter Card
>   image size `wpseo_twitter_creator_account` - Allow changing the
>   Twitter account as output in the Twitter card by Yoast SEO

**EDIT:**
A few things to remember:
Facebook scraps the url in the `og:url` tag (even if it's not the actual url you give it).
If you return `false` from the wp filter function, Yoast will not display that tag, so you can use it like that, and then manually add the tag somewhere else in your code where you need...

For example, here is some code to disable description and image tags for og and twitter:

```
 function yoast_og_tag ($tag) {
    return false;
 }
 $yfilters = [ 'wpseo_opengraph_desc','wpseo_opengraph_image','wpseo_twitter_description','wpseo_twitter_image' ];
 foreach ($yfilters as $k => $f) {
      add_filter( $f, 'yoast_og_tag', 10, 1 );
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yoast make various filters available. See their [WordPress SEO API Docs](https://yoast.com/wordpress/plugins/seo/api/) article for a list of them. So, for example, if you wanted to change the opengraph type of a blog post with ID `86`, you could use the `wpseo_opengraph_type` filter:

```
function modify_opengraph_type_p86( $type ) {
    if ( is_single( 86 ) )
        $type = 'video';

    return $type;
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_opengraph_type', 'modify_opengraph_type_p86' );
```

Comment: According to the docs, you can only change the OG type, and OG image, but you can't for `og:description`. Also there doesn't seem a way to control `twitter:` tags. Does anyone know of a way to acheive this?

Comment: I posted an answer with a solution to my comment question